# What does this line of code mean? ! inside of a Hash []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the line of code:

```
options[:selectors] = [[1, "Spain"], [2, "Italy"]]
v = "Monthly"

value = Hash[options[:selectors]][!!(v =~ /^[0-9]+$/) ? v.to_i : v]
```

The main part I'm not sure of is this part of the last line:

```
[!!(v =~ /^[0-9]+$/) ? v.to_i : v]
```

What does `[!!` mean, and what does `=~` mean? Lastly, what's the overall line mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!!` is an idiom that means "change this value into a boolean." The first `!` does the type conversion and the second `!` makes reverts the semantic meaning while keeping it a boolean.

This is not really appropriate in ruby, though. I believe it is a PHPism.

`=~` is a regex match.

Finally, the whole thing means "if v is an int string, make v an integer type and fetch from the hash, otherwise use the string as the key."

Comment: It's appropriate, but the `!!` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

The `!!` is a double negation, an idiom which is used to convert any object to a `true` or `false` value.

It works because any object besides `false` and `nil` evaluate to `true`. Negating the object produces `false`, and negating that result returns `true`:

```
object = Object.new

not object
# => false

not not object
# => true
```

If we try to negate `nil`, we get `true`, and if we try to negate that result, we get `false`:

```
object = nil

not object
# => true

not not object
# => false
```

The code:

```
!!(v =~ /^[0-9]+$/) ? v.to_i : v
```

Converts the value returned by the `v =~ /^[0-9]+$/` expression, which can be any object, to either `true` or `false`. The boolean value is then used as argument for the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

It means: if the string contains an integer, then convert it to one, otherwise just return the string.